# How to change the font size in Math mode in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

My text is in Persian/Kurdish and therefore I use a different font for the text and the font has different characteristics like height, I just want to change the font size that is used in Math mode. I want to add some statements perhaps in the preamble affecting the whole document.

Comment: Can you add a small example of code? Perhaps scaling the main font is simpler than scaling math.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LaTeX has a `\DeclareMathSizes` command to specify the math font sizes, by default this is

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{5}{5}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{7}{7}{5}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{6}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{\@xipt}{8}{6}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xviipt}{\@xviipt}{\@xiipt}{\@xpt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xiipt}
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xxvpt}{\@xxvpt}{\@xxpt}{\@xviipt}
```

so

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{\@xpt}{\@xpt}{7}{5}
```

says 10pt text font should use 10pt math font and 7pt in scripts and 5pt in scriptscript size

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{10}{9}{7}{6}
```

would make the math use 9pt 7pt and 6pt for a 10pt text font.

Comment: What about the others (`\DeclareMathSizes{\@xivpt}{\@xivpt}{\@xpt}{7}` for instance)? What do those macros stand for? I couldn't find any documentation for those.

Comment: @Andyc see latex.ltx (or source2e.pdf) they are just shorthands for 14pt (actually 14.4pt) and 10pt respectively. they saved a few bytes in the 1980s when every byte mattered but no need to use them if specifying new sizes.