# Smaller font for subscript within subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize, subscripts

How to get smaller font for subscript within subscript in math mode? For example, I want the subscript $c$ to be much smaller than it is in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a_{b_{c}}$
\end{document}
```

But "\scriptstyle" or "\scriptscriptstyle" is not working for some reason for subscripts within subscripts, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a_{b_{\scriptscriptstyle c}}$
\end{document}
```

has the same result for the size of $c$. So have to make $c$ even smaller?

Comment: Both your examples work properly for me (i.e., giving me the `b` in `\scriptstyle` and the `c` in `\scriptscriptstyle` ).

Comment: They produce the same result because they are they same. The first subscript is written using `\scriptstyle`, while the second (nested) one is written using `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Comment: Ok, but how to make $c$ even smaller?

Comment: Yes, I mean even smaller than it is.

Comment: If you make math items even smaller than `\scriptscriptsize` (the equivalent of `\tiny` in text mode), you should also be prepared to hand out magnifying glasses to the would-be readers of your documents.

Comment: For text inside MATH mode, using `$A_{\text{\tiny B}}$` worked for me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For *even* smaller, you could scale the sub-subscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$a_{b_{\scaleto{c}{1pt}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need consistency across a range of subscripts, you may wish to add a normalizer like a `\mathstrut`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
$a_{b_{\scaleto{c\mathstrut}{2pt}}}$
$a_{b_{\scaleto{g\mathstrut}{2pt}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, `\scaleto` from the `scalerel` package operates on its arguments in math mode by default, unlike `\scalebox` of the `graphicx` package, which operates in text mode.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `\DeclareMathSizes`; declare also other sizes if needed.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % arbitrary font scaling
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{7}{4}

\begin{document}
$a_{b_{c}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare to the standard and decide for yourself if it's worth the trouble. I wouldn't go below four points.

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg, can you tell me how to reduce di size of the subscript b please? I tried with \DeclareMathSizes{10}{5}{7}{4}, but an asterix appears where there was the letter a.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You're saying that at 10pt size you want normal math to be 5pt, first order scripts 7pt and second order scripts 4pt. Which doesn't really make sense, does it?

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification, now I know the meaning of the various parameters.

Comment: ...which is the difference between the first and the second parameter? The second allows me to choose the size of the normal math. What is normal math?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi The size for base symbols: in `$a_{b_{c}}$`, `a` has the size dictated by the second argument.

Comment: what is the first parameter? sorry for the nuisance.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi `\DeclareMathSizes{<current font size>}{<size for textstyle>}{<size for scriptstyle>}{<size for scriptscriptsize>}`. If the current size is 10pt, math will use the sizes declared with `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{x}{y}{z}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295861/4427

Answer (score 10):

Using someone's idea in [How to get an even smaller font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57673/5764) to scale `\scriptscriptstyle` content down by 30%:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

$a_{b_c}$

$a_{b_{\scalebox{.7}{$\scriptscriptstyle c$}}}$

\end{document}
```