# Inline math equation Point size

Tags: equations

How to change all equations point size(inline and display equations) globally,
point size worked in within `\begin{array}...\end{array}` but not changed
for `$....$`?[image]

Please find MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{stix}

\everydisplay{\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\everymath{\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont}

\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

Use the alternative calculation described above. In comparing the two values, you want to consider fluctuations in inventory over time.
Use the alternative calculation described above. In comparing the two values, you want to consider fluctuations in inventory over time.

$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon0123456789+-$
\bigskip

$\begin{array}{@{}l}\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon0123456789+-\end{array}$


\begin{align*}
\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon0123456789+-
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @David Carlisle: In my cases point size should vary each and every environment, example
in Box environment set Sans font(8/10), equations should be(10/12),
in quote environment set as times font(10/12) but equations should be(12/14),
above cases I cannot redefine within environments.

Comment: If you want I'l re-open but I suspect it is a duplicate in the end, you need to use DeclareMathSizes to set up math fonts, simply changing the text font size will not set up math in a consistent way inless the size you choose happens to have DeclareMathSizes already declared

Comment: Reopened by request but this appears to be a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295861/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-math-mode-in-latex

Comment: Hope `\everymath` may helps you...

Comment: @Yuvi: I used \everymath option, but it doesn't support for $...$ and \begin{math}...\end{math}

Comment: @RajeshN your last comment is misleading `\everymath` is executed for both `$` and `\begin{math}`

Comment: @David Carlisle: please refer my MWE file, that changing point size not update for $...$ and \begin{math}...\end{math}

Comment: @RajeshN yes but that is because `\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont` only changes the text fonts not because `\everymath` is not executed. See the answer I link to above you need to have used `\DeclareMathSizes` to set up the math sizes to use at a text font of 15pt. add `\typeout{EVERYMATH}` to your `\everymath` and you will see in the log that it is executed.

Comment: @David Carlisle: In the below cases same point size used for "quote" 
 and normal text, I want to reduce point size for inline math only inside of "quote" environments \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{stix}

\everymath{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{12}{8}{6}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont\sffamily Sample text $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon0123456789+-$}
\end{quote}
\bigskip

{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont Sample text $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon0123456789+-$}

\stop