# In line equation point size

Tags: equations

How to change all equations point size(inline and display equations) globally, point size worked in within \begin{array}...\end{array} but not changed for $....$? We cannot go option with
"\DeclareMathSizes{8}{8}{6}{5.5}" due to in my cases point size should vary each and every environment, example
in Box environment set Sans font(8/10), equations should be(10/12),
in quote environment set as times font(10/12) but equations should be(12/14),
above cases I cannot redefine within environments.[image]

Comment: How does this differ from your previous question: [Inline math equation Point size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528786)?  If they are the same, it would be better to edit the first one to clarify.

Comment: don't you just want to specify that if the text font is 8pt then the math font should be 10pt and if the text font is 10pt the math should be 12pt, that is exactly what \DeclareMathSizes` does,